# Building an expression from another expression in C#

Tags: c#, expression

I have a list of `Expression<Func<TRightModel, object>>` from which I need to build a list of `Expression<Func<TMiddleModel, object>>`

I have a property `TMiddleModel.RightModel` which gives the `RightModel` of a given `MiddleModel`. I tried this approach:

```
Expression<Func<TMiddleModel, object>> f = model =>
p.Compile().Invoke(model.GetRightModel());
```

(p is the `Expression<Func<RightModel, object>>`).

This compiles fine, but since the user of the 'f' needs to look into the expression, it fails at runtime.

Couldn't find any solution to this issue on google. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the static methods on [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx)

Comment: You will need to manually build a new expression tree from the old one, probably using a visitor, and replacing every occurrence of `model` with an `InvocationExpression` for `model.GetRightModel()`.